# CoreBluetooth XPC connection invalid error and Info.plist is added

Tags: swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = Database.database().reference()
    title = "cry"
    //self.delegate = delegate
    centralManager = CBCentralManager.init(delegate: self, queue: .main)            
}

extension ComposeViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    switch central.state {
    case .unknown:
        print("unknoe")
    case .resetting:
        print("reset")
    case .unsupported:
        print("unsupported")
    case .unauthorized:
        print("unauthorized")
    case .poweredOff:
        print("poweredoff")
    case .poweredOn:
        print("poweron")

        centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [CBUUID.init(string: Service_UUID)])
    }
}


func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    self.peripheral = peripheral
    print("discover peripheral")


    centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
}
```

I was getting the following message:

> [CoreBluetooth] XPC connection invalid

I was able to get poweron message and looks like I wasn't able to scan BLE devices. I add value in my Infoplist for Privacy bluetooth peripheral usage description NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription but no luck.

I tried to connect ESP32 and sending message to the LCD screen. The ESP32 is working good with BLE scanner app which I download from App Store.